# parent child job with common job and step listener in parent job

Tags: spring-batch

We have 10-15 diff spring batch jobs and for each job we have some common listener like email notifier, job duration listener etc. For this i have added parent job config and some common listener and package them as one lib.

Now in our main concrete jobs, i am using this parent job by extending them in child job context. something like this  where "parentJob" is defined in another common lib which has one job listener registered to it.

Now when i run my child job, it is not executing job listener registered in parent job. What could be the isssue?

Parent Job Def

```
<batch:job id="parentJob" abstract="true">
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobDurationListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

Child job

```
<batch:job id="job1" parent="parentJob">
    <batch:step id="step1"  >
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" start-limit="100" >
            <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="testListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

Comment: I want to add some clarification that, if I dont have any job listener registered in child job then it is invoking parent job listener and my parent job is abstract

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this question. I should have read documentation. After adding merge="true" in child job listener definition it has resolved the issue